# Basic click stats link in community promotion ads post is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

The following question recently appeared on Ask Ubuntu Meta:

> [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12379/community-promotion-ads-2015)

Notice that the question ID is `12379`.

The following Markdown snippet appears at the bottom of the question:

```
You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here][1].

  [1]: https://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/12380
```

Notice that the post ID in the link is `12380`.

Clicking the link leads to an empty page with a single link "Return to Question". However, the link takes me to [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12380) answer, which is the first answer posted for the question.

If I replace the ID in the link with `12379` (the ID of the question), I get [the expected page](https://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/12379).

Further investigation reveals that the question and answer both have the same timestamp. Since the obvious expected behavior of the link is that a list of ads would be displayed, I conclude that this is a bug.

Comment: What... bug.... it is just a typo! Or you think it should lead to 404?

Comment: No, the question is likely generated by a script and appears to be generating an incorrect URL.

Comment: Ok, edit it then...

Comment: Of course I can edit the question, but it should be prevented from happening in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a mechanical bug, it's a human typo. This is at current a manual system wherein I go and create (as of this date) 41 questions, and manually update the links on each one. I also at the same time create the default Twitter ad, and post them simultaneously.

In this case, because of the posting of answer and question simultaneously, the URL given is `http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12379/community-promotion-ads-2015/12380#12380`, wherein I accidentally copied 12380 instead of 12379. I might've slipped up on one or two other sites, so I s'pose I should go confirm they're all correct, haha.

Turns out I didn't mess up anywhere but on Ask Ubuntu. Welp.

Comment: They should really automate this!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My imagination went wild with this one, dreaming up a complex scenario involving race conditions.